# Is mfence for rdtsc necessary on x86_64 platform?

Tags: c++, linux, timestamp, x86-64, rdtsc

```
unsigned int lo = 0;
unsigned int hi = 0;
__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "mfence;rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi) : : "memory"
);
```

`mfence` in the above code, is it necessary?

Based on my test, cpu reorder is not found.

The fragment of test code is included below.

```
inline uint64_t clock_cycles() {
    unsigned int lo = 0;
    unsigned int hi = 0;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi)
    );
    return ((uint64_t)hi << 32) | lo;
}

unsigned t1 = clock_cycles();
unsigned t2 = clock_cycles();
assert(t2 > t1);
```

Comment: `mfence` should be issues after `rdtsc` for proper utilization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to perform a sensible measurement with `rdtsc` is a serializing instruction.

As it is well known, a lot of people use `cpuid` *before* `rdtsc`.
`rdtsc` needs to be serialized from *above* and *below* (read: all instructions before it must be retired and it must be retired before the test code starts).

Unfortunately the second condition is often neglected because `cpuid` is a very bad choice for this task (it clobbers the output of `rdtsc`).
When looking for alternatives people think that instructions that have a "fence" in their names will do, but this is also untrue. Straight from Intel:

> MFENCE does not serialize the instruction stream.

An instruction that is *almost serializing* and will do in any measurement where previous stores don't need to complete is `lfence`.

Simply put, `lfence` makes sure that no new instructions start before any prior instruction *completes locally*. See [this answer of mine for a more detailed explanation on locality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452772/x86-64-usage-of-lfence/37469559#37469559).
It also doesn't drain the Store Buffer like `mfence` does and doesn't clobbers the registers like `cpuid` does.

So `lfence / rdtsc / lfence` is a better crafted sequence of instructions than `mfence / rdtsc`, where `mfence` is pretty much useless unless you explicitly want the previous stores to be completed before the test begins/ends (but not before `rdstc` is executed!).

---

If your test to detect reordering is `assert(t2 > t1)` then I believe you will test nothing.
Leaving out the `return` and the call that may or may not prevent the CPU from seeing the second `rdtsc` in time for a reorder, it is unlikely (though possible!) that the CPU will reorder two `rdtsc` even if one is right after the other.

Imagine we have a `rdtsc2` that is *exactly* like `rdtsc` but writes `ecx:ebx`<sup>1</sup>.

Executing

```
rdtsc
rdtsc2
```

is highly likely that `ecx:ebx > edx:eax` because the CPU has *no reason* to execute `rdtsc2` before `rdtsc`.
Reordering doesn't mean random ordering, it means look for other instruction *if the current one cannot be executed*.
But `rdtsc` has no dependency on any previous instruction, so it's unlikely to be delayed when encountered by the OoO core.
However peculiar internal micro-architectural details may invalidate my thesis, hence the *likely* word in my previous statement.

---

<sup>1</sup> We don't need this altered instruction: register renaming will do it, but in case you are not familiar with it, this will help.

Comment: It turns out `mfence` is serializing like `lfence` on most CPUs, unfortunately.  [Are loads and stores the only instructions that gets reordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50496379).  See also Hadi's answer on [clflush to invalidate cache line via C function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51830976) for some actual experiments using `lfence; rdtsc; lfence`.

Answer (score 4):

**mfence** is there to force serialization in CPU before **rdtsc**.

Usually you will find **cpuid** there (which is also serializing instruction).

Quote from Intel manuals about using **rdtsc** will make it clearer

> Starting with the Intel Pentium processor, most Intel CPUs support
>   out-of-order execution of the code. The purpose is to optimize the
>   penalties due to the different instruction latencies. Unfortunately
>   this feature does not guarantee that the temporal sequence of the
>   single compiled C instructions will respect the sequence of the
>   instruction themselves as written in the source C file. When we call
>   the RDTSC instruction, we pretend that that instruction will be
>   executed exactly at the beginning and at the end of code being
>   measured (i.e., we don’t want to measure compiled code executed
>   outside of the RDTSC calls or executed in between the calls
>   themselves). 
>   The solution is to call a serializing instruction before
>   calling the RDTSC one. A serializing instruction is an instruction
>   that forces the CPU to complete every preceding instruction of the C
>   code before continuing the program execution. By doing so we guarantee
>   that only the code that is under measurement will be executed in
>   between the RDTSC calls and that no part of that code will be executed
>   outside the calls.

TL;DR version - without serializing instruction before rdtsc you have no idea when that instruction started to execute making measurements possibly incorrect.

HINT - use rdtscp when possible.

> Based on my test, cpu reorder is not found.

Still no guarantee that it may happen - that's why original code had `"memory"` to indicate possible memory clobber preventing compiler from reordering it.

Comment: As is mentioned above, `mfence` does not force serialization. Also note that the `"memory"` prevents _compiler_ reordering, but does not say anything about CPU reordering.

Comment: @MattG mfence does the same and more as lfence. Neither are full serialization instructions; but it seems unlikely that mfence won't wait till all previous instructions have finished locally as well. On top of that, it waits longer until also the stores have flushed to memory. Indeed it seems that the manual doesn't repeat the remark that lfence waits for all instructions to be finished locally for mfence; but it would be extremely odd if that wasn't the case. Normally one doesn't NEED to wait till stores are flushed to memory to continue here though as that is only relevant for other cores.

Comment: @CarloWood: That's only an implementation detail for `mfence`, but guaranteed by Intel's manuals for `lfence` and thus is future-proof.  There's some evidence that Skylake used to run `mfence` similar to a `lock`ed instruction, only being a memory barrier without being an out-of-order execution barrier.  But after an erratum was discovered, a ucode update strengthened `mfence` to include `lfence`.   See [Are loads and stores the only instructions that gets reordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50496379).  So once Intel gets this right, `mfence` won't block rdtsc.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think my remark was just speculation. In the meantime I wrote a full-blown benchmark lib for myself (ok, maybe not just for myself; this assembly stuff made its way into cwds, see [benchmark::Stopwatch](https://github.com/CarloWood/cwds/blob/master/benchmark.h)) and I wouldn't dream about using anything else than lfence, just because. Your remarks are of course correct.