# Know if CPU supports nanoseconds

Tags: c++, windows, performance, time, cpu

I am trying to get elapsed time in nanoseconds using C++ in visual studio. I did some testing and the measures always end with 00. Does it mean that my processor (Ryzen 7-1800X) doesn't support ~1 nanosecond resolution but only ~100ns? Can I enable it somehow?

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();    
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //stuff
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
    long long nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(elapsed).count();
    std::cout << "\n" << nanoseconds << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code? Are you using the `std::chrono` namespace for this?

Comment: There you go, yes, I'm using chrono @JasperKent

Comment: Then it would certainly imply than your processor doesn't support nanoseconds, so it's really a processor question rather than a C++ question as to whether you can enable it. Might be worth adding the processor as a tag on the question.

Comment: If you're using the Windows' High-Resolution timer, then (IIRC) 100 ns is the granularity of *that* - it's not dependent on the type of CPU.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks @AdrianMole

Comment: Is there a way to have more precision? @AdrianMole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MSVC 2015+ `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is based on `QueryPerformanceCounter`, which has a 100ns resolution.

On Windows, `QueryPerformanceCounter` is the fastest userland timer.
If you want an even higher resolution, you can try the RDTSC instruction ([`__rdtsc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/rdtsc?view=vs-2019)) which returns the CPU cycle counter. But it's a [very tricky one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189976/calculate-system-time-using-rdtsc) to use properly and is not recommended.

It seems on Windows you're pretty much stuck to a 100ns resolution. Keep in mind that in Windows world 100ns is a very short time - it equals roughly 300 instructions. Just one call to `QueryPerformanceCounter` already takes around 1000 instructions.