# Using eBPF to measure CPU mode switch overhead incured by making system call

Tags: linux, ebpf

As title, but the measurement result is unreasonable. Let me describe the current status.

I'm using syscall `getuid` as measurement target, I started by measureing the complete overhead with two `clock_gettime` bounded around, then measure the entry (what [SYSCALL](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall) instruction does before executing the actual `getuid` code) and leaving overhead saparately (with eBPF program hook onto the entry and leaving point).

The result for the complete overhead is ~65ns, and regarding to the entry and leaving overhead, it's ~77ns and ~70ns respectively.

It's obvious that my measurement has some additional overhead except the typical overhead. However, it's weird that since `clock_gettime` is a [vDSO](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) syscall, it should barely have noticeable overhead. And BPF, which is a [lightweight](https://lwn.net/Articles/437981/) instrumental tool (JIT-ed and etc.) these day in Linux, shouldn't have noticeable overhead too.

Is there anyone have idea what additional overhead my measurement incurs?

Following is my measurement code:

userland (measuring the return-from-kernel overhead):

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <bpf.h>
#include <libbpf.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <asm/errno.h>
#include <linux/if_link.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sched.h>

#define likely(x)   __builtin_expect((x),1) 
#define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect((x),0)
#define TEST_CNT 1000000
#define BPF_FILE_NAME "mkern.o"
#define BPF_MAP_NAME "msys"

static inline int sys_perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *attr, pid_t pid,
                                      int cpu, int group_fd,
                                      unsigned long flags)
{
    attr->size = sizeof(*attr);
    return syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, attr, pid, cpu, group_fd, flags);
}

static int attach_kprobe(int prog_fd)
{
    int err, fd, id;
    char buf[32];
    struct perf_event_attr attr = {};

    err = system("echo 'r:kp_sys_batch __x64_sys_getuid' > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/kprobe_events");
    if (err < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create kprobe, error '%s'\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    fd = open("/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/kprobes/kp_sys_batch/id", O_RDONLY, 0);
    if (fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open event %s\n", "sys_batch");
        return -1;
    }
    err = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (err < 0 || err >= sizeof(buf)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "read from '%s' failed '%s'\n", "sys_batch", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    close(fd);

    buf[err] = 0;
    id = atoi(buf);
    attr.config = id;
    attr.type = PERF_TYPE_TRACEPOINT;
    attr.sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_RAW;
    attr.sample_period = 1;
    attr.wakeup_events = 1;

    fd = sys_perf_event_open(&attr, 0/*this process*/, -1/*any cpu*/, -1/*group leader*/, 0);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("sys_perf_event_open");
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open perf_event (id: %llu)\n", attr.config);
        return -1;
    }
    err = ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);
    if (err < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ioctl PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE failed err %s\n",
               strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    err = ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_SET_BPF, prog_fd);
    if (err < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ioctl PERF_EVENT_IOC_SET_BPF failed: %s\n",
               strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void maxi_memlock_rlimit(void)
{
    struct rlimit rlim_new = {
        .rlim_cur   = RLIM_INFINITY,
        .rlim_max   = RLIM_INFINITY,
    };

    if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, &rlim_new)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limit!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

static int find_map_fd(struct bpf_object *bpf_obj, const char *mapname)
{
    struct bpf_map *map;
    int map_fd = -1;

    map = bpf_object__find_map_by_name(bpf_obj, mapname);
        if (!map) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed finding map by name: %s\n", mapname);
        exit(-1);
    }

    map_fd = bpf_map__fd(map);

    return map_fd;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int bpf_map_fd;
    int bpf_prog_fd = -1;
    int err;
    int key = 0;
    struct timespec tp;
    struct bpf_object *bpf_obj;
    struct reals map;
    struct bpf_prog_load_attr xattr = {
        .prog_type = BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE,
        .file = BPF_FILE_NAME,
    };

    maxi_memlock_rlimit();

    err = bpf_prog_load_xattr(&xattr, &bpf_obj, &bpf_prog_fd);
    if (err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed loading bpf object file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (attach_kprobe(bpf_prog_fd)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed attaching kprobe\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    bpf_map_fd = find_map_fd(bpf_obj, BPF_MAP_NAME);
    if (find_map_fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed finding map fd\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* warm up */
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_CNT; i++) {
        syscall(__NR_getuid); /* dummy call */
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp);

        if (unlikely(bpf_map_lookup_elem(bpf_map_fd, &key, &map))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to lookup map element\n");
            perror("lookup");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    uint64_t delta = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_CNT; i++) {
        syscall(__NR_getuid); /* dummy call */
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp);

        if (unlikely(bpf_map_lookup_elem(bpf_map_fd, &key, &map))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to lookup map element\n");
            perror("lookup");
            exit(-1);
        }

        delta += (1000000000 * tp.tv_sec + tp.tv_nsec) - map.ts;
    }
    printf("avg: %fns\n", (double) delta / TEST_CNT);

    return 0;
}
```

user land (measuring the enter-kernel overhead, almost same as the above, except what I pointed out):

```c
err = system("echo 'p:kp_sys_batch sys_batch' > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/kprobe_events");
...
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp);
syscall(__NR_getuid); /* dummy call */
...
delta += map.ts - (1000000000 * tp.tv_sec + tp.tv_nsec);
```

kernel land:

```c
SEC("getuid")
int kp_sys_batch(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    __u32 i = 0;
    struct reals *r;

    r = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&reals, &i);
    if (!r)
        return 1;

    r->ts = bpf_ktime_get_ns();

    return 0;
}
```

Except the additional overhead I mentioned above, inside the return-from-kernel measurement code, if the `echo 'r:kp_sys_batch sys_batch'` is changed to `echo 'p:kp_sys_batch sys_batch'` (which means that the measurement would take the syscall execution overhead into account), the result would be ~48ns, this means that the result includes overhead of syscall execution and return-from-kernel. Any idea why this could be only ~48ns?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the additional overhead is come from the retry of the seqlock? Both [`clock_gettime`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.84/source/lib/vdso/gettimeofday.c#L49) and [`bpf_ktime_get_ns`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.3/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L831) could encounter seqlock.

Comment: For clarification, `bpf_ktime_get_ns` refer to source at [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7-rc3/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L467) instead.